# How to initialize the array properly in state React

Tags: arrays, reactjs

Actually im calling an API and getting the result in the form like below and storing into variable result.

Im getting error TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. I think its because of not  initialising the result properly in state. Can anyone tell me how to initialize the array which is in the form like below.

```
{
    "numbers": [
        {
            "a": "one",
            "b": "two",
            "c": "three",
            "d": "four",
            "e": "five"            
        },
        {
            "a": "one",
            "b": "two",

        }
    ]
}
```

Iterating in this way :

```
{this.state.result.numbers.map((item, i) => {
                  return <li key={i}>{item.a}  {item.b}</li>
                                    })}
```

and initialising the var result in state

```
this.state = {
                result: []
             }
```

Comment: In state you have set the result as array, set it as `object`  `this.state = {result: {}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to map on `this.state.result.numbers`, you need to initialize `result.numbers` as an empty array:

```
this.state = { result: { numbers: [] } }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining **state.result** as an **Array** and trying to assign **json object** to it. which is wrong.
Either you add the API response at an index of **state.result** array or try converting **this.state** to

```
{ result : {}}
```